# Efficiently finding the closest zero of an arbitrary function

Tags: math, glsl

In summary, I am trying to start at a given `x` and find the nearest point in the positive direction where `f(x) = 0`. For simplicity, solutions are only needed in the interval `[initial_x, maximum_x]` (the maximum is given), but any better reach is desirable. Additionally, a specific precision is not mandatory; I am looking to maximize it, but not at the cost of performance.

While this seems simple, there are a few caveats that make the solution more difficult.

1. Performance is the first priority, even over some precision. The zero needs to be found in the fewest possible calls to `f(x)`, as this code will be run many times per second.
2. There are not guaranteed to be any specific number of zeros on this line. There may be zero, one, or many places that the function intersects the x-axis. (This is why a direct binary search will not work.)
3. The function `f(x)` cannot be manipulated algebraically, only supporting numerical evaluation at a discrete point. (This is why the solution cannot be found analytically.)

My current strategy is to define a step size that is within an acceptable loss of precision and then test in increments until an interval is found on which there is guaranteed to be at least one zero (in [a,b], a and b are on opposite sides of 0). From there, I use a binary search to narrow down the (more) exact point.

```
// assuming y != 0
initial_y = f(x);
while (x < maximum_x) {
  y = f(x);
  // test to see if y has crossed 0
  if (initial_y > 0) {
    if (y < 0) {
      return binary_search(x - step_size, x);
    }
  } else {
    if (y > 0) {
      return binary_search(x - step_size, x);
    }
  }
  x += step_size;
}
```

This has several disadvantages, mainly the fact that there is a significant trade-off between resolution and performance (the smaller `step_size` is, the better it works but the longer it takes). Is there a more efficient formula or strategy I can take? I thought of using the value of `y` to scale the step size, but I cannot figure out how to preserve precision while doing that.

The solution can be in any language because I am looking more for a strategy to find the zeros, than a specific program.

(edit:)

The function above is assumed to be continuous.

To clarify the question, I understand that this problem may be impossible to solve *exactly*. I am just asking for ways to improve the speed or precision of the algorithm. The one I am currently using is working quite well, even though it fails during many edge cases.

For example, a solution that requires fewer steps with similar precision or another algorithm that increases the precision or reliability with some performance impact would both be extremely helpful.

Comment: Your strategy is sensible, but it doesn't guarantee that you'll find the *first* root (even within the given tolerance) since you'll be skipping over intervals with an even number of roots. Don't know that you can do much better in general, not without knowing at least something about the target function. Consider that a completely *arbitrary* function could be a "pathological" one like `sin(1/x)` or `floor(1/x) mod 10` with infinitely many zeros near the point you are starting from.

Comment: That is the issue. In essence, I am working with a user-created function, so I cannot guarantee it will act in any particular way. And, I understand what you are saying, that is why I am looking for an improvement. The current implementation has many errors when the function has many close zeros and often fails in edge cases.

Comment: This is impossible to solve. In order to get some sensible answers you need to put some constraints.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is essentially impossible to solve in the general case. For example, no algorithm can find the "first" root of `sin(1/x)`, starting from `x=0`.

A tentative answer is by exponential search, i.e. starting from a small step and increase it following a geometric progression rather than an arithmetic one, until you find a change of sign. But this will fail if the first root is closer than the initial step, or if the first root is followed by a close one.

Without any information on the behavior of `f`, I would not even try anything (but a "standard" root finder), this is too hopeless ! (But I am sure you do have some information.)

Comment: I don't quite understand how an exponential search would help. Wouldn't it just decrease the precision the closer it got to the answer, and therefore decrease the reliability and precision of the final answer?

In relation to the behavior of `f`, I cannot narrow it down much more, since it is user-defined. However, I can say that it represents a parametric equation of a line substituted into a 3D surface. Would it help to link to my current implementation?

Comment: @KiranWells: my final word about this: "Without any information on the behavior of  `f`, I would not even try anything (but a "standard" root finder), this is too hopeless !"